# Slow rendering of Rails view according to newrelic statistics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, view, newrelic

I am seeing a performance problem with rails view rendering.
According to Newrelic Stats:

[image: newrelic stats]

This slow rendering *randomly* appears during requests.

- Could this problem be connected to slow file reading from the file system?
- Is there any way to debug it in lower level?

Comment: That screenshot appears to be broken...

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I'm not sure I'm interpreting what's going on in that screenshot correctly)

Your view rendering seems to be slow not because of the Ruby code that it runs (which takes 0.219s), but because it does 8 SQL queries that take over a second each. You might just need to optimise those queries (e.g. return fewer results, add indexes to the tables, etc).